# JQuery / JCarousel: Using WrapInner and nth selectors to only wrap every 8th item

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I want to use JCarousel to display UL elements with LI containing only eight images (two rows of four), something that looks like this:

**`<li>`
`<div>`
[image][image][image][image]

[image][image][image][image]
`</div>`
`</li>`
`<li>`
`<div>`
[image][image][image][image]

[image][image][image][image]
`</div>`
`</li>`**

I thought a good way to do this would be to use `after()` to add some closing and opening tags like so:

```
$(".jcarousel-item img:nth-child(9)").after(</div></li><li><div>);
```

But I guess I am misunderstanding the nature of `after()`, because it won't seem to insert closing tags unless they lead with opening tags.

Is there a better way to do this with `wrapInner()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're starting with a single `ul` with a single `li` with a `div` containing a whole bunch of images & you want to split it into a set of `li`s, each containing 8 images right? If so, this will work:

```
var images = $("img");
while (images.length > 8) {
    images.slice(8, 16).appendTo("ul").wrapAll("<li><div></div></li>");
    images = images.slice(16);
}
```

Basically it slices off 8 image chunks from the collection of images and appends them back into the `ul` in their own `li`s (it leaves the original `li` with the 1st 8 images). Obviously, you'd need to adjust your selectors as presumably you've got other images and unordered lists on your page.

**Edit**: to explain the reason why `.after` is not working the way you were expecting it to - I believe jQuery tries to manipulate the DOM rather than the raw HTML. So you can't just append random chunks of HTML unless they can be parsed and turned into actual DOM nodes. In other words the content you pass to `.after` effectively needs to be a valid and complete piece of HTML in its own right. So, because jQuery can't work out how to turn something like "`</div></li><li><div>`" into a node, it acts a bit strangely (I'm guessing in this case it ignores the two initial close tags, since they don't make sense on their own & then create's the `li` & `div` nodes & then effectively auto-closes them for you).